# Symfony3 issue on Locale Based on the User Preference (from database)

Tags: php, symfony, locale

vaersion Symfony 3.1.3

I want set the locale based on the user preference so I have added the following to the **User Entity**

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="locale", type="string",nullable=true)
 * @Expose
 */
protected $locale;

/**
 * Set locale
 * @param string $locale
 * @return Users
 */
public function setLocale($locale)
{
    $this->locale = $locale;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get locale
 * @return string
 */
public function getLocale()
{
    return $this->locale;
}
```

the above is working fine I can CRUD the locale value in the database

and then, following this guide [Setting the Locale Based on the User's Preferences](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html#setting-the-locale-based-on-the-user-s-preferences) I have created the `UserLocaleListener` and when I debugging it as follow

```
public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

    if (null !== $user->getLocale()) {
        $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
        print($this->session->get('_locale'));die;
    }
}
```

the `print($this->session->get('_locale'));die;` gives the expected result which is stored locale value (fr, nl or en) in the database.

But when I use

`echo $locale =  $request->getLocale();die;` in the controller

and

`{{ app.request.getLocale() }}` in the twig

the result is always **en**

even the database stored value is **nl** or **fr**.

So my question is from where this **en** is populating when I use `$request->getLocale()` and `app.request.getLocale()`?

and

How to avoid this **en** and set the database stored value as the locale?

Also please let me know if I want to Edit/Update this with any other information.

Comment: You have to implement first part as well (`onKernelRequest` listener).

Comment: yes :) it is the answer